# ip neighbor show going in loop for kernel2.6.10

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have MVL2.6.10 kernel version in my switch,and whenever I have around 100 arp entries , in that mostly stale entries, if I run "ip neighbor show" it's going into loop, but "arp -a" working perfectly, I didn't find any patch for this issue.
Only "ip neighbor show" going in loop.Any help much appreciated.